# Azure API Managment - Configure operations through Code

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, we can create operations through the Portal. See below link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-add-operations/

Is there anyway to configure the Operations through C#/Code instead of portal?

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have REST APIs as well as PowerShell cmdlets.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn894081.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible

when you export it to yaml and then you can import with bicep.

so you can create a variable like the following:

```
var operation = loadTextContent('openapi.yaml')
```

as format you have to use openapi when you using this variable

[APIM - Deploy APIs using Bicep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068425/apim-deploy-apis-using-bicep)

I can confirm that the serviceUrl needs to be filled.