# APIM - Deploy APIs using Bicep

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I am trying to export an existing API and import using Bicep.
Error I am getting is "Validation error-The field serviceUrl is invalid"

```
module apis_resource 'apis/deploy.bicep' = {

  name:'${uniqueString(deployment().name, parLocation)}-Apim-Api-0'

  params: {

    apiManagementServiceName: apiManagementService.name

    displayName: 'Tortue ADT API V1'

    name: 'TortueADTAPIV1'

    format:'openapi+json'

    value:loadTextContent('apis/TortueADTAPI.json')

    path:'/getTwinbyquery'

    subscriptionRequired:true

  }
}
```

Exported API template

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test API",
        "description": "",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "https://zneetwdn11apim00.azure-api.net"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/gettwinbyquery": {
            "post": {
                "summary": "getTwinByQuery",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "gettwinbyquery",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "apiKeyHeader": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "name": "subscriptionKey",
                "in": "header"
            },
            "apiKeyQuery": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "name": "subscriptionKey",
                "in": "query"
            }
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
            "apiKeyHeader": []
        },
        {
            "apiKeyQuery": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceUrl is the url for backend service and I think it needs to be set, at least per this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

The code snippet leads me to think that you are using the apim module from ResourceModule repo:

https://github.com/Azure/ResourceModules/tree/main/modules/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis

In that implementation the default value set for the parameter is set to empty, so I'm not exactly sure if it's supposed to work with empty value. I'm not an APIM expert, but I think the bicep implementation of an API might actually need that value to be set to something.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to reproduce the above issue and find the below one

1.Open azure portal and select the app you what to redeploy

2.Goto **properties** on the right-side search for **Resource ID** copy the Id and shown below
[image]

3. open the vs code application and create a file with `.bicep` extension
4. Goto right side and click **ctrl+shift+p** it will open a command palette and search for   **Bicep: insert Resource** paste the **Resource ID** in that
   as show below

[image]

[image]

AFAIK, if we give the same name, it will give an error the app name is already exist

So, We have the change the name to different places as shown below

[image: https:// https://i.imgur.com/CAwPw5O.png]

[image]

[image]

To convert from bicep to json uses below command in Azure CLI

```
 bicep build main.bicep
```

So it will create a `.json` format file in the same file location

Now used the below command to deploy it again into azure portal

```
az deployment group create --resource-group ResourceGroupName --template-file FileName.json
```

[image]

[image]

final output deployed to azure portal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HTWN.png